# what is wrong in Second Order Differential Equation?

Tags: matlab, scilab

### My code is

I am trying to plot a graph of second order differential equation

```
clc;
funcprot(0);
function dx = f(t,x)
dx(1) = x(2);
dx(2) = sin(2 * t);
endfunction
t = 0: 0.1 : 4 * %pi;
y = ode ([0,-1/2],0,t,f);
plot2d(t',[y(1,:)',y(2,:)']);
xlabel('t'); ylabel('y and derivative');
xtitle('Plot of solution of 2nd order ODE')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just transpose the initial condition:

```
clc;
funcprot(0);
function dx = f(t,x)
dx(1) = x(2);
dx(2) = sin(2 * t);
endfunction
t = 0: 0.1 : 4 * %pi;
y = ode ([0,-1/2]',0,t,f);
plot2d(t',[y(1,:)',y(2,:)']);
xlabel('t'); ylabel('y and derivative');
xtitle('Plot of solution of 2nd order ODE')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will mark this as the answer.